# Input accept="image/png" is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EHAJEToF/1/edit)

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png">
```

It's expected that the file dialog accepts png files only. But `accept="image/png"` does not work on Firefox. How can I make it?
P.S. It works in Chrome.

Comment: we are almost in 2015 and some browsers do not support the `accept` properly. this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently there's an issue specific to Firefox with some extension types. You can read more about this bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176).

The latest update on this bug is from a couple of months ago and it seems to not yet be resolved. For now, I would suggest server-side file-checking, or at the very minimum you can use JavaScript to verify the file's extension before it gets uploaded.

Comment: Server-side checks should be performed regardless.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, agreed 100%, but that doesn't solve the OP's problem and it can cause unnecessary traffic that can be mitigated with javascript.

Comment: Beside validation problems there is an UX issue that user possibly has to browse through many files in order to find the one to upload, instead of having correct files filtered out.

Comment: The issue will be fixed when Firefox 37 is released - estimated April 2015.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers describe, Firefox just does not support `type="image/png"` yet. Instead, it ignores the attribute and does not apply any file filter. Using `type="image/*"` would work, but then the filter would allow all image files.

Perhaps the best practical workaround is to use JavaScript code that checks for the file name extension. It does not really prove anything, but close to 100% certainty, PNG files have names ending with .png and other files don’t. Sample code (replace the rude `alert` by a function that suit your UI design):

```
<form action="..."
enctype=multipart/form-data method=post
onsubmit="return checkPNG(document.getElementById('img'))">
<label for=img>Your image (.png):</label>
<input type=file id=img name=img accept=
"image/png, .png" onchange="return checkPNG(this)">
<input type=submit value=Send>
</form>
<div id=f></div>
<script>
function checkPNG(el) {
  if(el.value) {
    var parts = el.value.split('.');
    if(parts[parts.length - 1].toLowerCase() === 'png') {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Please specify a PNG file.');
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
</script>
```

The downside is that when scripting is turned off, Firefox will accept any file, even though `accept="image/*"` would at least restrict the files to image files. However, JavaScript being disabled is probably rare enough, as compared with the trouble of browser sniffing needed to server different `type` attributes to different browsers.

You should naturally check the file types on the server before doing anything with the files, since any filtering of file types is easily bypassed, by accident or intentionally-

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I modified your code to check all the extensions listed in the original accept attribute and posted another answer (mentioning yours).

Answer (score 1):

To make Firefox partially respect the accept attribute you can use this code, copied and modified from Jukka K. Korpela's answer (thanks!+1), with the added bonus of respecting the original item accept attribute, not juts for PNGs, not just one extension.

```
function checkFileExt(el) {
    var accept=el.getAttribute("accept");
    if(el.value && el.value!="" && accept && accept!="") {
        var parts = el.value.split('.');

        if(parts.length==1) {
            alert("File with no extension: '"+el.value+"'. Allowed: "+accept);
            return false;
        }

        var ext=parts[parts.length - 1].toLowerCase();

        accept=accept.split(',');
        var found=false;
        for(var i=0;i<accept.length;i++) {
            if("."+ext==accept[i]) {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Wrong file: '"+el.value+"'. Allowed: "+accept);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<input name="fle_txt" value="" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx" onchange="checkFileExt(this);" type="file">
```

It will not work with mime types or groups like `image/*` (it will just ignore them), but could be modified to add a list of extensions for every mime type [like appending `.jpg,.jpeg` to the array `accept` if it finds `image/jpeg` in it]

Answer (score 0):

[Read Mozilla Doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept)
Currently not all browsers go to that deep to support specific file extention, but they all support a file type, like image/video.

```
accept
If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifiers:
A valid MIME type with no extensions
audio/* representing sound files HTML5
video/* representing video files HTML5
image/* representing image files HTML5
```

Answer (score -3):

the 'accept' attribute is not **properly** supported by any of the major browsers.
For form validation you should use php, or javascript.

Comment: That's a really misleading answer.. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) says otherwise

Comment: @sushain97, If you read into my answer you'd see that in this case w3schools is actually correct and this attribute is indeed supported, but not for all file extensions. Since it's supported in chrome and IE and to some extension in FF, that makes this answer very misleading.