# How to restrict input type="file" to accept only jpg image not working in Fire Fox

Tags: html, file, input, jpeg

This code is working in Crome and IE but not in Fire fox. In fire fox it just show a suggestion in drop down box to select jpg image. But I want it to work like crome and IE. And is it possible to do this in Fire fox without using javascripts, just using HTML? Thanks in advance.

```
<input id="uploadTopicImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the attribute 'accept'  is not globally  supported by  major browsers. You can use a javascript validation on the form onsubmit event to verify if the file type is correct, returning false otherwise.

Note: Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads should be validated on the server.  because malicious users can rename .exe to jpg and upload it to server

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [Input accept="image/png" is not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866315/input-accept-image-png-is-not-working-in-firefox)

To summarize, this is a known "bug" in Firefox, which is still not solved.

Comment: I saw that post but I want to know if it is possible using any attr to input tag without using js so I asked this question again. Thanks.