# BUG - Firefox Version 47.0 <input accept="" issue

Tags: html, firefox

Does anyone know why this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="xx" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
<input class="uu" onchange="" type="file" name="p" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

allows the user to select any file type instead of only the types I specify in accept? (FireFox Version 47.0) Is this standardised across browsers or browser specific? I don't know if this is a bug or not?

**Believe this is now a bug... Only confirmed for MacOS X**

Comment: What does "accepts all files" mean? The file browser doesn't filter?

Comment: **edited question. I mean that it allows the user to select any file instead of the image files I specified

Comment: According to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176 it was fixed last year

Comment: And according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866315/input-accept-image-png-is-not-working-in-firefox you can fix with `accept="image/*"`, because the problem is with png extensions only.

Comment: Marcos that does work to an extent however it allows images types I don't want like svg... I guess it's better than allowing everything but still not ideal. And still annoying because I don't want to have different code to cater for FF...

Comment: You can use a javascript code, a simple javascript can validate if the extension is valid or not, and a server-side script to check it is better. This kind of things are not firefox only, are for your security. Even a kid can remove the `accept` attribute on the HTML, but not a kid can debug all javascript and server-side checkings. This code should be very very simple and makes your website more robust

Comment: Yes Marcos I have these checks on the backend but it's not a good user experience to allow a file that I then come back with an error message and reject...

Comment: [Works for me on Windows 7](https://i.imgur.com/NgUukiA.png) :-?